# Camera 'twisting' in three.js

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to get to grips with the basics of three.js and don't understand why the camera is behaving as it is, nor how to fix it.

Here's a really simple test setup that I'm using, stripped back to bare bones.

HTML is just:

```
<html>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="500"></canvas>
    <script type="module" src="test-camera.js"> </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and `test-camera.js` is this:

```
import * as THREE from 'https://unpkg.com/three@0.122.0/build/three.module.js'

async function main() {
    // Scene
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();

    // Camera
    const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, 2, 0.1, 500);
    camera.position.set(0, -20, 2);
    camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);

    // Plane
    const pGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(50, 50);
    const pMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xffff00, side: THREE.DoubleSide });
    const plane = new THREE.Mesh(pGeometry, pMaterial);
    scene.add(plane);

    // Mesh
    const mGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(10, 10, 10);
    const mMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
        color: 0xff0000
    });
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(mGeometry, mMaterial);
    scene.add(mesh);

    // AmbientLight
    var light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff);
    scene.add(light);

    // renderer
    const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas });
    renderer.setSize(1000, 500, false);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

main().catch((e) => {
    console.error('error:', e);
});
```

So it's just a box on a plane with a camera looking at it. (What could possibly go wrong??)

I want to move the camera to view the box from various angles - so changing the camera.position.set() parameters "should" make this just work as long as the camera.lookAt remains pointing at (0,0,0)? But if I do anything other than head along the negative y axis (this code has the camera at (0,-20,2)), the camera seems to twist so the scene appears rotated.

I understand that the camera by default begins looking along the z-axis, with the x-axis heading left to right and the y-axis heading bottom to top - and so I get why this particular position for the camera results in the scene looking as I want it.

But how to do get the camera to maintain the plane being 'down'? I want to move the camera to (20,0,2) just for one example, and still have my z axis pointing up in the canvas.

Incidentally, this isn't about the user moving the camera, Orbit controls, etc - I just want to understand how to make the code produce the view I want.

I suspect I'm missing something fundamental... any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so at long last I've found camera.up which, of course, solves the problem entirely. I don't know why I hadn't seen that in any of the example code I'd looked at but that's the thing I was after.

For clarity, if (as in my example above) my x-y plane is the ground then setting `camera.up = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,1)` ensures that the z-axis is always facing up in the scene as it is rendered.